# Updating value of previously sent ecommerce transactions

Tags: google-analytics

I am installing ecommerce tracking for a pretty simple ecommerce site. I am tracking the conversion on the order confirmation page, recording the transaction ID and order value, and everything's working fine.

However, sometimes the system issues the customer an offer to make an additional purchase on the order confirmation page with a single click (some small accessories that are discounted). If the customer chooses to make an additional purchase, I would like to be able to update the previously sent conversion. I do not want to assign a new transaction ID, because that will artificially inflate my conversion rate. I have tried sending the new amount of revenue with the same transaction ID, however that does not seem to have consistent results (sometimes ignored, sometimes value is just doubled).

I cannot hold back sending the conversion to GA until the customer makes a decision, because oftentimes the customer simply exits the browser without stating whether he is going to accept or decline the offer - in this case no conversion data would be sent at all.

Any ideas? Is there something in the GA library that I'm missing for this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is nothing. Even if a transaction with the same id goes through it's internally treated as a second transaction w/r/t the conversion rate.

If you want to get really fancy you could try and collect the transaction hit on your own server, wait a few minutes to see if you need to add another product and [add a queue time parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) to offset for the actual collection time before you send it to Google. While this would work in theory I am not sure it is really feasible in a production environment (and in any case it would probably be more work than it's worth).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found this article about reversing a transaction: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en - do you think it's possible in this case to reverse the original transaction and then create a new one for the higher amount?

Comment: This will cancel out the revenue (you have to set campaign parameters so the counter transaction is attributed to the correct advertising channel, else you ruin your channel reporting), but this is still counted as two transactions (even says so in the article). Plus they cancel each other out only as long as both transaction and countertransaction are within the selected timeframe, else you will see them separately. Frankly I think this is bad advice, even if it comes from Google themselves, and it will definitely not solve your problem (since conversions rates will still be affected).